# Calculate php mysql results sum dynamically

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, database

I have a table with product price model cost stock etc, to make it easier I calculate the total customer pay for for each product like this

```
<?php echo number_format($show['quantity'] * $show['product_price'],0,',','.'); ?>
```

I need to show the total sum of this calculation but as you can see they are calculared in PHP real time. Is there a way to do it?

Here is the complete code

```
<?php
$result=mysqli_query($database,"SELECT * FROM `products` order by `category` ASC");
$rows=mysqli_num_rows($result);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
?>

<table class="sales">

<tr>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Product Cost</td>
<td>Customer Pays</td>
</tr>        

<?php if($rows){$i=0;while($show=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo number_format($show['quantity'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo number_format($show['product_cost'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo number_format($show['quantity'] * $show['product_cost'],0,',','.'); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php }}?>
</table>

TOTAL CUSTOMER PAY FOR ALL PRODUCTS = EXAMPLE $10.234
```

**If there are 5 different products in the results with different prices and different Customer Pays I need to sum all those Customer Pays and show here**

```
<?php }else{?> 

No products to show

<?php }?>
```

**EDIT: SOLVED**

The solution is

```
<?php
$count = mysqli_query($database, "SELECT SUM(stock * cost) AS totalPaid
FROM products");
while($total = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count)){
     echo number_format($total['totalPaid'],0,',','.');} ?>
```

Thanks to the correct answer of McAdam331

Comment: `SELECT SUM(quantity * product_cost)`?

Comment: Why not assign `number_format($show['quantity'],0,',','.')` and `number_format($show['product_cost'],0,',','.')` to variables so you can just echo those variables and do your multiplication on the fly?

Comment: Because the products have different prices it won't work

Comment: If there are 5 products with 5 different prices and totals it is that I must sum the total of all 5 items

Comment: No, what @the_pete is saying can be done.

Comment: You just assign them at the start of the foreach loop so each time the variables are reset to the new values.

Comment: Any example how? Maybe in an answer using my code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `SUM` as part of your SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity * product_cost) AS totalPaid
FROM myTable
GROUP BY customer;
```

I'm just guessing you'd group on customer based on the clues in your question, but you can change that to whatever you need.

Comment: Edited my question the part where I show the result in BOLD, please take a look

Comment: I think my answer still applies, as this `SUM`s the customerPays column.

Comment: It gave me a result but because the list of products is around 100 I will sum with calculator and tell you about it. But the amount seems correct

Comment: It was perfect I solved it. I will ass the code it solved to my question so people in the future see how to do